# Extract a word with specific prefix

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with lines such as:

```
27/12/20 | 05:50:48pm | abcdefgh  |ID:1:418856791 | jack | 1.1.1.1:1111 | IN | GN-4536 | LOL | 0
27/12/20 | 05:51:44pm | abcdefgh  |ID:1:503729784 | jill | 2.2.2.2:2222 | IN | GN-497187 | LOL2 | 0
```

There is a big file with such lines. How can I extract only `GN-4536` and `GN-497187` from this file? Like it can be anything `GN<-numbers>`. How can I get the output in format like:

```
GN-number
GN-number
GN-number
GN-number
```

I tried using `sed` and `grep` commands but It could extract the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy with `cut`:

```
$ cut -f8 -d'|' filename
 GN-4536 
 GN-497187
```

This cuts the `8`th `f`ield `d`elimited by `|` (which must be escaped from the shell).

But it leaves in the whitespace. You can strip that with `tr`.

```
$ cut -f8 -d'|' filename | tr -d ' '
GN-4536
GN-497187
```

Answer (score 0):

we can try with below command , Tested and worked fine

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^GN-[0-9]*$/){print $i}}}' filename
```

output

```
GN-4536
GN-497187
```